# Why this UTF-8 error is solved with a simple \clearpage

Tags: pdftex, unicode, input-encodings

An example is shown below, which also includes a description of the problem:

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{CJKutf8}

\begin{document}
\begin{CJK*}{UTF8}{gbsn}

Some Chinese text.

一些中文
\section{一些中文}

Compiling this with pdflatex will generate the following common error:

%! PACKAGE INPUTENC ERROR: UNICODE CHAR \U8:Ɨ� NOT SET UP FOR USE WITH LATEX.

However, when a clearpage command is included at the end of the document
(i.e., to uncomment the line below), then the error will disappear and the
document compiles correctly.
%\clearpage  % This is important; otherwise there will be a nasty UTF-8 error.

If we delete section command, the document also compiles correctly
(even without clearpage).

\end{CJK*}
\end{document}
```

My question is: why does the `\clearpage` command solve the problem?

Comment: I can't reproduce this problem. My method: Duplicate your two lines of Chines enough times to get multiple pages. Compile. It went without a hitch. Perhaps your setup is old? I run on an up to date TeXLive 2015.

Comment: I get always an error with your document above, but because of the error line you included. If I remove it everything works fine. Is the error you get really in uppercase?

Comment: @HaraldHanche-Olsen That's my fault; now I edited the file, which can readily reproduce the problem in my computer; I am using the 2014 version of TeXLive though.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Now I edited the example file, which may be a bit clearer.

Comment: If you replace the section command with `\section[]{一些中文}´, it compiles cleanly. So it's most likely a problem with a moving argument.

Comment: @HaraldHanche-Olsen Thanks!  Yes that works, though I still don't quite understand why (since \section{something} is the normal way of using it).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It happens when latex tries to typeset the page heading. This happens at page shipout time; if the `CJK*` environment has ended before the last page ships out, the necessary definitions for doing the typesetting are gone, and you get this error.

You see this clearly if you add `\errorcontextlines=99` to your document (outside the `CJK*` environment please). Also, the problem goes away with `\pagestyle{empty}` (same caveat), further supporting my diagnosis.

You have already found the proper workaround: Add `\clearpage` where you did.

**Edited** to add this version of the workaround – with thanks to egreg in the comments:

```
\AtBeginDocument{\csname CJK*\endcsname{UTF8}{gbsn}} 
\AtEndDocument{\clearpage\csname endCJK*\endcsname}
```

And then, of course, you remove the `CJK*` environment from within the document body.

Comment: I guess there's a way for telling that the whole document is in Chinese, without enclosing it in a `CJK` environment

Comment: @egreg I would certainly hope so! Unfortunately, `texdoc CJKutf8` produces a less than helpful result. I'll leave the digging to others.

Comment: I found that `\AtBeginDocument{\csname CJK*\endcsname{UTF8}{gbsn}}` and `\AtEndDocument{\clearpage\csname endCJK*\endcsname}` seem to work.

Comment: @egreg That's a neat way to do it. I added it to the answer.

Answer (score 9):

The problem is that the section command sets a header. The problem is that the the CJK environments ends before the header is typeset and so the chinese chars are no longer set up. Using `\clearpage` makes the CJK-environment span two pages so that is is active when the header is typeset, but is clearly only a work-around. The second problem is that the book class headers are set with \Makeuppercase which can do a lot of harm (that's beside other the reason why the error message uses capitals).

```
\documentclass{book}
\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{\markright{\thesection.\ #1}} %no uppercase

\usepackage{CJKutf8}


\begin{document}
\begin{CJK*}{UTF8}{gbsn}

Some Chinese text.

一些中文
\section[\protect\begin{CJK*}{UTF8}{gbsn}一些中文\protect\end{CJK*}]
        {一些中文}

Compiling this with pdflatex will generate the following common error:

%! PACKAGE INPUTENC ERROR: UNICODE CHAR \U8:Ɨ� NOT SET UP FOR USE WITH LATEX.

However, when a clearpage command is included at the end of the document
(i.e., to uncomment the line below), then the error will disappear and the
document compiles correctly.
%\clearpage  % This is important; otherwise there will be a nasty UTF-8 error.

If we delete section command, the document also compiles correctly
(even without clearpage).

\end{CJK*}
\end{document}
```